# How to save to vb.Net .Settings file?

Tags: vb.net, settings.settings

I'm able to pull values from settings in my .settings file, but unable to write to them.

Here's what I've tried:

```
My.Settings.Item(SettingsName) = Me.SettingProperty1
```

error message:

```
SettingsPropertyNotFoundException was unhandled
The settings property 'property1Value' was not found.
```

[image]

Comment: That will happen if `SettingsName` is not present in the collection.  Be sure whatever value `SettingsName` has is a valid Settings item.  That will save the value to the collection, but wont save the settings to disk.

Comment: Thanks, @Plutonix. Added a picture of what my file looks like.

Comment: The most likely cause is that `SettingsName` does not hold the value you think it does.  When it crashes hold the mouse over it and see if that value exists in the Settings table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in my `FormClosing` event handler...

```
My.Settings.YourSettingName = YourValue
```

Edit: This might not be what you're asking for.

If you're just wanting to save the settings:

```
 My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Maybe I've got the wrong type of settings file? I'm using the `.settings` file template. It allows settings to be added with `Name/Type/Scope/Value`s

Comment: I've never had a reason to directly edit the Settings.settings file. I just go to the properties of my project (double-click "My Project") and click the "Settings" tab on the left.

Comment: Oh. I'm trying to have something that would allow me to save/update string values from the app. Is this not the appropriate file type to use?

Comment: I think you only need the first line of code I posted then. It should update the settings when called.

Comment: Yes. Gosh, I'm sorry. i'm just tired today and was doing something weird on my end. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that proprety as the Set attribute, you probably just have the get

Comment: I'm new to VB--could you give me an example? Is this going in the Settings.vb file?

Comment: The VS designer creates a Property wrapper for each setting item. The designer file should NOT be edited as it says at the top: `Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if  the code is regenerated.`

Comment: So how am I to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I now take full responsibility for reading and writing settings. I avoid using VS to Bind Settings through Property-Grid.

I added a public `BOOLEAN` to `my.settings` called `OkToChange_Settings`. I set it `True` after my main Form fires the `SHOWN` event.

If any `Event` or `Accessor` invokes code causing a Settings-Change (especially before `SHOWN`), it must check `OkToChange_Settings == True`, else exit.

Worked for me...